# Разница между enum и enum class

Tags: c++, c++11

В чём разница между `enum` и `enum class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enum конвертируется в int без предупреждения, т.е. он фактически является int-типом.

enum class будет отдельным типом.

т.е. `enum class colors {red, green}` нельзя случайно превратить в enum class `dangerLevel {red, yellow, green}`, только принудительно скастить

спасает от ошибок, поскольку программисту придется подумать, прежде чем скастовать цвет светофора в уровень опасности

Comment: а минусы какие?

Comment: минусов нет, разве что ручное кастование, некоторых это бесит (возможно), других  нет. скорость работы кода  - не падает. это просто более строгая языковая конструкция, которая на этапе компиляции проверяется.

Comment: Если нужно ручками кастить энум, значит скорее всего проблема в дизайне кода. и для некоторых багоделов это действительно минус. А еще небольшой минус - это сериализация-десиреализация - приходиться приводить ручками. Но тут один раз написал и забыл.

Comment: Еще минус: несовместимость с C, но это не всем важно.

Comment: На самом деле обычному enum тоже можно указать тип (не обязательно int). Ещк олин важжный + enum clasd - это то, что его значения не светятся в глобальной области видимости